# How to use useEffect hook to post a request to postgresql

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

In a quiz application I am trying to add a question and an answer to my database in PostgreSQL.

Here I have a text area box and an input box to send to my database in PostgreSQL. I added a handelsend function and fetch to post the data to my databases getting an error of

> CreateQuiz.js:21 POST http://localhost:4000/createQuiz net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. and this error following it. CreateQuiz.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch.

looking to use useEffect hooks instead.

````
import Header from "../components/Header";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

export default function CreateQuiz() {
  const [sent, setSent] = useState(false);
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  const [answer, setAnswer] = useState("");
  const handleSend = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const quiz = {
      question,
      answer,
    };
    setSent(true);

    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/createQuiz`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(quiz),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("new quiz created");
    });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <div style={{ minHeight: "900px" }} className="primary-color center form">
        {!sent ? (
          <form>
            <div>
              <h1 className="primary-color">Create yor quiz here.</h1>
              <textarea
                placeholder="put your question here"
                value={question}
                id="myTextarea"
                cols="30"
                rows="10"
                onChange={(e) => setQuestion(e.target.value)}
              ></textarea>
            </div>

            <input
              placeholder="answer"
              value={answer}
              id="answer"
              name="answer"
              type="text"
              onChange={(e) => setAnswer(e.target.value)}
            />
          </form>
        ) : (
          <h2>Question and answer added</h2>
        )}
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSend}>
          Submit
        </button>
        <button>Next Question</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: Can you add a `.catch((e) => console.log(e))` to your fetch.then (eg. fetch(..).then(..).catch(..)) and share with us the error.

Additionally, is your API working correctly on localhost:4000/createQuiz? Have you tested it with postman or something else to make sure it accepts post requests appropriately?

Comment: Yes I tested with postman and it sends questions and answers to my postgresql database

Comment: in the terminal I'm getting this error: null value in column "questions" of relation "quiz" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Can you share the backend code of your route `/createQuiz` as well

Answer (score 0):

change following line

```
.then((res) => {
       console.log(res.json())
       console.log("new quiz created");
}
```

so you can check your promise status

almost in can be backend problem